# Backup chrome stored password

Tags: google-chrome, password, backup, password-recovery

My harddisk is corrupt but some part of it is available.
I booted my ubuntu from USB Pen Drive and now I would like to copy the saved passwords by chrome to an external harddrive in order to I can reuse them when I reinstall the Ubuntu to a new disk.

Unfortunately I am not able to start chrone anymore.

Comment: It's normally under `/home/username/.config/chromium/Default/Login Data` but `password_value` will be encrypted, so you can't transfer it without decrypting, I'm not sure how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wrote a script that gets passwords from Chromium and decrypts them.
Decryption parts taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153159/decrypting-chromium-cookies

https://gist.github.com/sh4dowb/10a64a954e3c6af895620fa0ebc83853

Run these commands:

```
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sh4dowb/10a64a954e3c6af895620fa0ebc83853/raw/9b439556f09fc9d2313dd9d832c4c87804a316cc/retrieve_password.py
python3 retrieve_password.py
cat passwords.csv
```

You can then import CSV file to another machine/browser, I think

**Note:** I think you use Chromium, if you're using **google-chrome**, in the code replace `Chromium Safe Storage` to `Chrome Safe Storage` and `chromium` in path to `google-chrome`